# How to get child ID of parent contenteditable div on keydown?

Tags: javascript, html

I'm trying to get back children id on **keydown** event but so far i had only luck with click event.

When i'm doing with keydown event my solution got me parent ID back but with click event i got children ID back.

Do you have any idea how can i achieve this but with **keydown** event?

```js
// Refernce the parent of all of the target nodes
var parent = document.getElementById('parent');
// Register the click event to #parent
parent.addEventListener('keydown', idNode);

// This is the callback that is invoked on each click
function idNode(e) {
  /* If the node clicked (e.target) is not the 
  || the registered event listener 
  || (e.currentTarget = #parent)
  */
  if (e.target !== e.currentTarget) {
    // Get the #id of clicked node
    var ID = e.target.id;
    // Reference e.target by its #id
    var child = document.getElementById(ID);

  }
  // Log the #id of each e.target at every click
  console.log('The caret is located at ' + ID);
  
  // Return the e.target as a DOM node when needed
  return child;

}
```

```html
<div id="parent" contenteditable="true">
  <div id="child-1" tabindex="-1">
    One
  </div>
  <div id="child-2" tabindex="-1">
    Two
  </div>
  <div id="child-3" tabindex="-1">
    Three
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: What exactly you want to achieve? Returning from an event handler is not useful, as the value is not received anywhere.

Comment: I'm trying to get  ID of child div when keydown is at one of these three divs. This is working correctly with click event but when i replace click with keydown event i get parent element back. I just want to see it for now with console log and later implement in my project.

Comment: That happens because unfocusable elements (like `div`) don't normally fire `keydown` event (not even when in a content editable wrapper). If you'd add `tabindex="-1"` to the divs inside the wrapper, then you'll get the id of the actual div the keydown was fired. But as `document.getElementById` returns the exact same element as `e.target`, why to bother to make a DOM traversion in the first place?

Comment: I have edited code snippet as you mentioned but now it's returning undefined for child ID.  And yeah e.target when 'keydown' event is fired is returning parent id rather than child ID.

Comment: You've to forget IDs altogether when working with dynamic content. It looks like you need to get the surrounding element of what is selected (the caret itself is an empty selection).

Comment: e.target.id = e.currentTarget.id = 'parent'  in KeyboardEvent

Answer (score 0):

Check out this snippet:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>

</head>
<body>
    <div id="parent">
        <div id="child-1" contenteditable="true">
            One
        </div>
        <div id="child-2" contenteditable="true">
            Two
        </div>
        <div id="child-3" contenteditable="true">
            Three
        </div>
    </div>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        // Refernce the parent of all of the target nodes
        var parent = document.getElementById('parent');
        
        // Register the click event to #parent
        parent.addEventListener('keydown', idNode, false);

        // This is the callback that is invoked on each click
        function idNode(e) {
          /* If the node clicked (e.target) is not the 
          || the registered event listener 
          || (e.currentTarget = #parent)
          */
          var ID, child;
          if (e.target !== e.currentTarget) {
            // Get the #id of clicked node
            ID = e.target.id;
            // Reference e.target by its #id
            child = document.getElementById(ID);

        }
          // Log the #id of each e.target at every click
          console.log('The caret is located at ' + ID);
          
          // Return the e.target as a DOM node when needed
          return child;

        }
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Basically you making parent  editable, so KeyboardEvent receiving id of parent  only. Instead of parent I have set `contenteditable="true"` on child s which make sure KeyboardEvent find out right target.

Answer (score 0):

Ids in dynamic content are hard to manage, as the user can remove elements with an id, and create new elements without an id. Refer the elements in a content editable with references only.

Only focusable elements (like form control elements and an editable, also `document`) can fire a keydown event. An unfocusable element doesn't participate on KeyboardEvent firing in any way, the event really fires on the element it is attached, it's not bubbling up from the seemingly targeted element (the element the caret is positioned to). The seemingly targeted element isn't also included in any of the properties of KeyboardEvent object.

You've to use [Selection Object](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Selection) to get the element where the caret lies when KeyboardEvent fires. Something like this:

```js
const parent = document.getElementById('parent');

parent.addEventListener('keydown', idNode);

function idNode(e) {
  const selection = window.getSelection(),
    target = selection.anchorNode.parentElement;
  console.log(target);
}
```

```html
<div id="parent" contenteditable="true">
  <div id="child-1">
    One <span>Plus</span>
  </div>
  <div id="child-2">
    Two
  </div>
  <div id="child-3">
    Three
  </div>
</div>
```

There are multiple ways to get the selected element from `Selection` object, the above code is just an example. As a sidenote, returning from an event handler function is not useful, as there's no place in the code where you could receive the returned value (the value is returned to the event queue).